# How to iterate through an object when it is not an array type

Tags: java, loops, object, member

My object `LabOrder` contains data that cannot locate with array index. What I want to do is print the non-null values in the object like `name = John`. How can I iterate through that non null values and print?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over all attributes? Can you edit the class?

Comment: Overwrite `toString` method of that object, if you have access to the code.

Comment: you can use reflexion for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899045/how-to-get-all-attributes-of-a-class

Comment: Yes i want to iterate through all attributes. In that object one attribute called name will be there. So what i exactly want to do is pass that name in to decrypt method. Because it is in the encrypted format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use reflection to iterate over the object's fields:

```
Field[] fields = obj1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : fields) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String name = field.getName();
    Object value = field.get(obj1);
    if (value != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use reflection. This will help you:

```
ClassABC abc = new ClassABC();
for (Field field : abc.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String name = field.getName();
    Object value = field.get(abc);
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", name, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

LabOrder order = new LabOrder();// Instantiation of the bean.
LabOrder order = Introspector.getBeanInfo(LabOrder.class);
  for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDesc : order.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
      String propertyName = propertyDesc.getName();
      Object value = propertyDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(order);
      System.out.println(propertyName);
      System.out.println(value);
  }
```