# Call method from child class stored in property

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm creating a validation class for my project.
At the moment I'm stuck on the point that I want to invoke a method (in this case `getText()`) from a class that is being passed via a generic type.

Here are the codes:

In this class I created a getRules where I pass a HashMap where the key is the name of the field, and the value in the rules attached to it.

```
public class PlayerValidator extends FormValidator<PlayerFormPanel> {
  @Override
  protected HashMap<String, String> getRules() {
    HashMap<String, String> rules = new HashMap<>();
    rules.put("firstNameField", "required");

    return rules;
  }
}
```

Next I got a parent class where I got a validate method, which will iterate over the rules and check if the rule is valid or invalid.

```
abstract class FormValidator<T> {

  abstract HashMap<String, String> getRules();

  public void validate(T form) {
    System.out.println(form.toString());

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> field : getRules().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(field.getKey());
        System.out.println(field.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

In the generic type `T` I get the `PlayerFormPanel` object, but how would I be able to call the `getText()` method on the `firstNameField` (field.getKey())?

Comment: `field.getKey()` returns a String: it doesn't have a `getText()` method.

Comment: In the getKey(), there will be the `TextField` object of `firstNameField`. So it should have the `getText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) or Reflection

```
for(PropertyDescriptor prop : Introspector.getBeanInfo(class).getPropertyDescriptors()){
  System.out.println(prop.getReadMethod());
}
```

Possible duplicate of this question: 
[Java Reflection: How can i get the all getter methods of a java class and invoke them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524011/java-reflection-how-can-i-get-the-all-getter-methods-of-a-java-class-and-invoke)