# Reflector: How to list getters of a class and invoke them in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

The following SO post shows very nicely how to use introspector to list the getters associated with a class.

[Java Reflection: How can i get the all getter methods of a java class and invoke them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524011/java-reflection-how-can-i-get-the-all-getter-methods-of-a-java-class-and-invoke)

The code I am using from this post is:

```
for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : 
  Introspector.getBeanInfo(User.class,Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()){
  System.out.println(propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod());          
}
```

This works fine for my 'User' class, with the output being:

```
public java.lang.String com.SingleEntity.mind_map.User.getName()
public int com.SingleEntity.mind_map.User.getNumber_of_entries()
public java.lang.String com.SingleEntity.mind_map.User.getUser_created_date()
```

My question now is, how do I now invoke those methods?  If this is explained somehow in the linked SO I apologise but I don't understand it and would really appreciate an example.

Naturally I know how to invoke a Class method normally, but the assumption here is that the getters are unknown to the program until the above code discovers them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod()` returns a `Method` object.

Simply use `Method.invoke(Object instance, Object... args)`.

Something in the lines of...

```
for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : 
Introspector.getBeanInfo(User.class,Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()){
    try {
        Object value = propertyDescriptor
                       .getReadMethod()

               .invoke(myUserInstance, (Object[])null);      
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        // TODO
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException iaee) {
        // TODO
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you ever so much.  You just need to add a closing brace to close off the try statement.

Comment: @SingleEntity you're welcome! And thanks for pointing out the typo - fixing now :)