# How to get Getter and Setter of a Hibernate class via reflexion

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, reflection, getter-setter

I want to have a depper look into java reflection and hibernate.
To pass values to a known setter works, but I want to do the same with an unknown setter of a hibernate pojo.
I get the mapped class with

```
PersistentClass mappedClass = session.configuration.getClassMapping(classFromPath.getName());
Table myTable = mappedClass.getTable();
iter = myTable.getColumnIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
     Column myColumn = (Column) iter.next();
     Property myProperty = mappedClass.getProperty(myColumn.getName());
     System.out.println(myProperty.getName());
}
```

This is my way, to get a specific property. Now, I want to get the propertys getter and setter methods.
One way is to get the name, to concate the words get/set with the property names. I don't like that way and want a better solution.
I know, there is a function like myProperty.getSetter, but I'm not sure, how to deal with it.

I'm totally wrong? Are there any ways to get the getter/setter methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/beans/Introspector.html) and [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) for this.

For details, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524011/java-reflection-how-can-i-get-the-all-getter-methods-of-a-java-class-and-invoke)

Comment: I found out, that these tools just query method like "get"+"variablename". boolean-getters like "isUseful" (see java naming standard) could not be found.